# SVG invisible on Safari without height attribute, but issue not recreatable?

Tags: svg, safari

I have an SVG in my website which displays fine on Chrome but isn't visible on Safari and Mobile Safari.

Weirdly, if I copy and paste the SVG into a Codepen page then it works fine, so I'm not able to recreate the issue publicly.

```html
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512" width="22" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" role="img"><path fill="currentColor" d="M4.686 427.314L104 328l-32.922-31.029C55.958 281.851 66.666 256 88.048 256h112C213.303 256 224 266.745 224 280v112c0 21.382-25.803 32.09-40.922 16.971L152 376l-99.314 99.314c-6.248 6.248-16.379 6.248-22.627 0L4.686 449.941c-6.248-6.248-6.248-16.379 0-22.627zM443.314 84.686L344 184l32.922 31.029c15.12 15.12 4.412 40.971-16.97 40.971h-112C234.697 256 224 245.255 224 232V120c0-21.382 25.803-32.09 40.922-16.971L296 136l99.314-99.314c6.248-6.248 16.379-6.248 22.627 0l25.373 25.373c6.248 6.248 6.248 16.379 0 22.627z"></path></svg>
```

Setting `height 100%` as an attribute fixes the issue in Safari and doesn't make it the wrong size or aspect ratio.

What is going on here? Why does this work and is a safe fix? And also why is the issue not reproducible?

UPDATE: Ive now been able to recreate. Safari hides the SVG when it has a parent div with `display: flex`:

https://codepen.io/adsfdsfhdsafkhdsafjkdhafskjds/pen/yLPgaJx

```
<div>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512" width="22" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" role="img"><path fill="currentColor" d="M4.686 427.314L104 328l-32.922-31.029C55.958 281.851 66.666 256 88.048 256h112C213.303 256 224 266.745 224 280v112c0 21.382-25.803 32.09-40.922 16.971L152 376l-99.314 99.314c-6.248 6.248-16.379 6.248-22.627 0L4.686 449.941c-6.248-6.248-6.248-16.379 0-22.627zM443.314 84.686L344 184l32.922 31.029c15.12 15.12 4.412 40.971-16.97 40.971h-112C234.697 256 224 245.255 224 232V120c0-21.382 25.803-32.09 40.922-16.971L296 136l99.314-99.314c6.248-6.248 16.379-6.248 22.627 0l25.373 25.373c6.248 6.248 6.248 16.379 0 22.627z"></path></svg>
</div>
```

If I set the container div to `display: block` or set a height on the SVG then it comes back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As comments @Evanss

> Also height auto doens't make the SVG appear, but height 100% does.

***width="22" height="100%"***

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512" width="22" height="100%"  aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" role="img" style="border:1px solid red">

  <path fill="currentColor" d="M4.686 427.314L104 328l-32.922-31.029C55.958 281.851 66.666 256 88.048 256h112C213.303 256 224 266.745 224 280v112c0 21.382-25.803 32.09-40.922 16.971L152 376l-99.314 99.314c-6.248 6.248-16.379 6.248-22.627 0L4.686 449.941c-6.248-6.248-6.248-16.379 0-22.627zM443.314 84.686L344 184l32.922 31.029c15.12 15.12 4.412 40.971-16.97 40.971h-112C234.697 256 224 245.255 224 232V120c0-21.382 25.803-32.09 40.922-16.971L296 136l99.314-99.314c6.248-6.248 16.379-6.248 22.627 0l25.373 25.373c6.248 6.248 6.248 16.379 0 22.627z">
  </path>
  </svg>
```

The snippet above doesn't render the image correctly, but if you save the svg as a separate file and open it in a browser, you'll see exactly the same image.

In the image below, the red rectangle is the border of the svg canvas with `width="22"` and `height="100%"`

[image]

As you can see, with this SVG configuration, paddings  are too large. What is unacceptable and will interfere with layout

> Using JavaScript isnt idea as it may cause the page to flicker

Using the JavaScript method ***getBBox()***  in the snippet console allows you to find out the physical dimensions of the svg shape
In this case, JS is not involved in the SVG rendering process and is only a reference tool.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 32 448 512" width="22" height="100%" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" role="img" style="border:1px solid red">
  <path id="path" fill="currentColor" d="M4.686 427.314L104 328l-32.922-31.029C55.958 281.851 66.666 256 88.048 256h112C213.303 256 224 266.745 224 280v112c0 21.382-25.803 32.09-40.922 16.971L152 376l-99.314 99.314c-6.248 6.248-16.379 6.248-22.627 0L4.686 449.941c-6.248-6.248-6.248-16.379 0-22.627zM443.314 84.686L344 184l32.922 31.029c15.12 15.12 4.412 40.971-16.97 40.971h-112C234.697 256 224 245.255 224 232V120c0-21.382 25.803-32.09 40.922-16.971L296 136l99.314-99.314c6.248-6.248 16.379-6.248 22.627 0l25.373 25.373c6.248 6.248 6.248 16.379 0 22.627z">
  </path>
 </svg>
 <script>
   console.log(path.getBBox())
 </script>
```

In the console, we can see the physical dimensions (dimensions that are given by the path of the svg shape)

```
  "x": 0,
  "y": 31.999996185302734,
  "width": 448,
  "height": 448
```

To move the image to the top left corner (this is the svg`s  origin) we set the value` viewBox="0 32 448 448"` And to reduce the margin margins we set fixed values width="22" height="22"

### Recommendations for creating and using icons

> Setting both dimensions would be very time consuming as I have a lot
> of icons with the same issue.

1. If you are using some unique icons created by a designer, then you cannot avoid the manual positioning and scaling process for each icon described above.

***There is no universal solution for this case. It all depends on how the icon was drawn.***

2. If the icon is simple, standard, then it is better to use icons drawn by professionals. There are many such resources on the web.
   **In this case, manual, additional processing is not required.**
3. You can use [google-fonts character font](https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#using-the-icons-in-html)

Icons by name can be selected [here](https://material.io/icons/)
The name of your icon - ***Close `Fullscreen***

Below is an example with minimal layout

```css
span {
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  margin-top:0.5em;
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
}
span:hover {
  transform: scale(2); 
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<span class="material-icons"> close_fullscreen </span>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have the height of the SVG twice. In view styles hight="100%" and `style="height: auto;"`

safari doesn't know which style to prefer, how to scale the SVG, so it doesn't display the image.

Leave one style: `width="22" height="auto"`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512" width="22" height="auto" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" role="img" style="border:1px solid red">
  <path fill="currentColor" d="M4.686 427.314L104 328l-32.922-31.029C55.958 281.851 66.666 256 88.048 256h112C213.303 256 224 266.745 224 280v112c0 21.382-25.803 32.09-40.922 16.971L152 376l-99.314 99.314c-6.248 6.248-16.379 6.248-22.627 0L4.686 449.941c-6.248-6.248-6.248-16.379 0-22.627zM443.314 84.686L344 184l32.922 31.029c15.12 15.12 4.412 40.971-16.97 40.971h-112C234.697 256 224 245.255 224 232V120c0-21.382 25.803-32.09 40.922-16.971L296 136l99.314-99.314c6.248-6.248 16.379-6.248 22.627 0l25.373 25.373c6.248 6.248 6.248 16.379 0 22.627z">
  </path>
 </svg>
```

### Update

Try setting the values of `viewBox="0 32 448 448" according to the dimensions shown by the JS method getBBox()

And also specify fixed width and height viewport width="22" height="22"

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 32 448 448" width="22" height="22" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" role="img" style="border:1px solid red">
  <path id="path" fill="currentColor" d="M4.686 427.314L104 328l-32.922-31.029C55.958 281.851 66.666 256 88.048 256h112C213.303 256 224 266.745 224 280v112c0 21.382-25.803 32.09-40.922 16.971L152 376l-99.314 99.314c-6.248 6.248-16.379 6.248-22.627 0L4.686 449.941c-6.248-6.248-6.248-16.379 0-22.627zM443.314 84.686L344 184l32.922 31.029c15.12 15.12 4.412 40.971-16.97 40.971h-112C234.697 256 224 245.255 224 232V120c0-21.382 25.803-32.09 40.922-16.971L296 136l99.314-99.314c6.248-6.248 16.379-6.248 22.627 0l25.373 25.373c6.248 6.248 6.248 16.379 0 22.627z">
  </path>
 </svg>
 <script>
   console.log(path.getBBox())
 </script>
```

Comment: Sorry I accidentally copied the inline style as I was trying things out with the browser dev tools. The bug persists without this, ive updated the code in my question.

Comment: Also height auto doens't make the SVG appear, but height 100% does.

Comment: @Evanss Update answer

Comment: Using JavaScript isnt idea as it may cause the page to flicker. Setting both dimensions would be very time consuming as I have a lot of icons with the same issue.

Comment: @Evanss Thanks for the feedback. It would be difficult to give a detailed answer in the comments, which would indicate the ways and methods of solving your problem.  Therefore, I would like to give an additional answer

Answer (score 1):

In my case, adding the `svg` attributes `width="40"` and `height="auto"` did the trick for Safari to show the svgs correctly:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 503.8 503.8" width="40" height="auto">
    <style>.st0{fill:currentcolor}</style>
    <path d="M251.9 45.4c67.3 0 75.3.2 101.8 1.5 24.6 1.1 37.9 5.2 46.8 8.6a79.6 79.6 0 0 1 29 18.9 78.2 78.2 0 0 1 18.8 28.9c3.5 8.9 7.6 22.3 8.7 46.8 1.2 26.6 1.5 34.6 1.5 101.8s-.3 75.3-1.5 101.8c-1.1 24.6-5.2 37.9-8.7 46.8a83.4 83.4 0 0 1-47.8 47.8c-8.9 3.5-22.2 7.6-46.8 8.7-26.5 1.2-34.5 1.5-101.8 1.5s-75.2-.3-101.8-1.5c-24.5-1.1-37.9-5.2-46.8-8.7a78.2 78.2 0 0 1-28.9-18.8 79.6 79.6 0 0 1-18.9-29c-3.4-8.9-7.5-22.2-8.6-46.8-1.3-26.5-1.5-34.5-1.5-101.8s.2-75.2 1.5-101.8c1.1-24.5 5.2-37.9 8.6-46.8a78.4 78.4 0 0 1 18.9-28.9 78.4 78.4 0 0 1 28.9-18.9c8.9-3.4 22.3-7.5 46.8-8.6 26.6-1.3 34.6-1.5 101.8-1.5m0-45.4c-68.4 0-77 .3-103.8 1.5S102.9 7 86.9 13.2a124.9 124.9 0 0 0-44.6 29.1 123.6 123.6 0 0 0-29.1 44.6c-6.2 16-10.5 34.3-11.7 61.2S0 183.5 0 251.9s.3 77 1.5 103.9 5.5 45.1 11.7 61.1a125.3 125.3 0 0 0 29.1 44.7 123.4 123.4 0 0 0 44.6 29c16 6.2 34.3 10.5 61.2 11.7s35.4 1.5 103.8 1.5 77-.2 103.9-1.5 45.1-5.5 61.1-11.7a128.6 128.6 0 0 0 73.7-73.7c6.2-16 10.5-34.3 11.7-61.1s1.5-35.5 1.5-103.9-.2-77-1.5-103.8-5.5-45.2-11.7-61.2a123.4 123.4 0 0 0-29-44.6 123.1 123.1 0 0 0-44.7-29.1c-16-6.2-34.3-10.5-61.1-11.7S320.3 0 251.9 0Z"></path> 
    <path d="M251.9 122.6a129.4 129.4 0 1 0 129.4 129.3 129.3 129.3 0 0 0-129.4-129.3Zm0 213.3a84 84 0 1 1 84-84 84 84 0 0 1-84 84Z"></path> 
     <circle cx="386.4" cy="117.4" r="30.2"></circle>
</svg>
```